# Как не обнулять значение переменной

Tags: java, android

В базу данных должны попадать значения date, answer1 и answer2. Из них в БД я вижу только date. Места answer1 и answer2 пусты в таблице. Я подозреваю, что строки answer1 и answer2 становятся пустыми после окончания обработки `RadioGroup`. Но не могу понять, как это исправить

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    DBHelper dbHelper;
    public String date;
    public String answer1;
    public String answer2;

    @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
    public void onButtonStartInterviewClick(View view) {

        LinearLayout LLQ1 = findViewById(R.id.LLQ1);
        LinearLayout LLQ2 = findViewById(R.id.LLQ2);

        Button BSI = findViewById(R.id.buttonStartInterview);
        BSI.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        LLQ1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

// Текущее время
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        date = dateFormat.format(currentDate);

//заполнение столбцов
        RadioGroup RGQ1 = findViewById(R.id.RGQ1);
        RGQ1.setOnCheckedChangeListener((group, checkedId) -> {
            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.radioButtonQ1A1:
                    answer1 = (getString(R.string.Q1Answer1));
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButtonQ1A2:
                    answer1 = (getString(R.string.Q1Answer2));
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButtonQ1A3:
                    answer1 = (getString(R.string.Q1Answer3));
                    break;
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), answer1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            LLQ2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            LLQ1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        });

        RadioGroup RGQ2 = findViewById(R.id.RGQ2);
        RGQ2.setOnCheckedChangeListener((group, checkedId) -> {
            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.radioButtonQ2A1:
                    answer2 = getString(R.string.Q2Answer1);
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButtonQ2A2:
                    answer2 = getString(R.string.Q2Answer2);
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButtonQ2A3:
                    answer2 = getString(R.string.Q2Answer3);
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButtonQ2A4:
                    answer2 = getString(R.string.Q2Answer4);
                    break;
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), answer2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            LLQ2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        });
        
        //работа с бд
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();//обращение к БД
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_DATA, date);
        contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_Q1, answer1);
        contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_Q2, answer2);
        database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_ANSWERS, null, contentValues);
        dbHelper.close();

    }
```

P.s. в коде много radiogroup, поэтому при сокращении кода мог убрать что-то нужное. Но код в целом рабочий, кроме вставки значений в БД

Comment: Они не обнуляются, они изначально пустые

Comment: `setOnCheckedChangeListener` намекает же когда сработает этот метод и переменные переопределятся.

Answer (score 0):

Установка слушателя - это как поручение:
"Вася, пойдёшь в магазин - возьми мне минералки".
И вы не можете её выпить, пока Вася не вернётся (если вообще вернётся) из магазина.
То есть следом за установкой слушателя вы не можете использовать значения, потому что они будут выбраны когда-нибудь потом.
Нужно делать запись в самом слушателе `OnCheckedChangeListener`:

```java
        RadioGroup RGQ2 = findViewById(R.id.RGQ2);
        RGQ2.setOnCheckedChangeListener((group, checkedId) -> {
            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.radioButtonQ2A1:
                    answer2 = getString(R.string.Q2Answer1);
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButtonQ2A2:
                    answer2 = getString(R.string.Q2Answer2);
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButtonQ2A3:
                    answer2 = getString(R.string.Q2Answer3);
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButtonQ2A4:
                    answer2 = getString(R.string.Q2Answer4);
                    break;
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), answer2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            LLQ2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        
            //работа с бд
            dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();//обращение к БД
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_DATA, date);
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_Q1, answer1);
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_Q2, answer2);
            database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_ANSWERS, null, contentValues);
            dbHelper.close();
        });
```